# How to implement email application in android

Tags: android, email

I want to implement email application which has all options like inbox,compose,drafts and etc. I don't know even how to start. I know how to send mails from our application.

But it is synchronizing with existing mails like gmail,hotmail. can any one please tell me any reference links, any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source of of [K9mai](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/)l.. and save yourself from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: That source should answer all your questions or more. You should work on accepting useful answers.